# Want to use paragraph in vb but don't want to use labels

Tags: html, vb.net, user-interface, paragraph

I am now designing window forms in vb. I am familiar with HTML design and controls in vb.net . What I wonder is whether can I design paragraphs in vb as in HTML and I don't want to use labels. Pls, your advices and experiences would be helpful for me.

Comment: I know about using rich text boxes but if there are better ways for paragraphing , let me know, pls.

Comment: It really depends on your requirements.  If you just need to display information, you could use your Html knowledge and load a Webbrowser control.  Just set `Webbrowser.DocumentText="your html"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this without a label, textbox or any other windows tool.

If your purpose is to make a design with html code, you can use a control named Web browser, create the html page and display it with this control. But I don't think it could be very helpful as the HTML page will be separate from the app, and so you will lose making full control over it.

If it is possible, creating a web project using asp.net instead of windows project, will be the best solution.